# Oracle 11g XE 64bits installation problem on Windows 7

Tags: oracle, windows, installation

I had to install Oracle 11g XE on my laptop under Windows 7.
So I follow this [Tutorial](http://www.hanmiaojuan.com/2013/03/install-oracle-xe-11g-for-windows7-64bits.html). The installation didn't even fail once, and seem to be OK.
But every time i tried to connect to it with SQLPLUS, it failed with **ORA-12638** error...

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
```

After some search I found this [Web Site](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12638_credential_retrieval_failed.htm) and attempt to resolve my problem with the second solution. But then I get another kind of error : **ORA-01034** and **ORA-27101**...

```
SQL> connect
Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

It seem that my database didn't even exist to begin with...
And if looking in `[...]\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE`, there is no files.

When looking the logs at `[...]\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\log`, I found that during the installation process, the application wasn't even able to connect to the database created.

Example in the file : **postDBCreation.log**

```
SQL> connect "SYS"/"&&sysPassword" as SYSDBA
ERROR:
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed 
[...]
SQL> startup ;
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
SQL> select 'utl_recomp_begin: ' || to_char(sysdate, 'HH:MI:SS') from dual;
SP2-0640: Not connected
SQL> execute utl_recomp.recomp_serial();
SP2-0640: Not connected
```

Another file in the same directory : **CloneRmanRestore.log**

```
SQL> startup nomount pfile="D:\Applications\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\scripts\init.ora";
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
SQL> @D:\Applications\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\scripts\rmanRestoreDatafiles.sql;
SQL> set echo off;
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
SP2-0640: Not connected
ERROR:
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed
```

I am log as a domain user with administration right on the laptop, so why does the installation fail without putting an explicit error ? And how to ensure that the installation of Oracle 11g XE on my laptop work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more than 6 hours to fix this, I found this [post](https://community.oracle.com/message/10982625#10982625) which help me to understand the problem.

The problem was that I tried to install Oracle 11g XE with my user account connected on the enterprise domain. The installation process, then, wasn't able to connect to the database. I suspect that it try to connect to it from the enterprise domain, and not from localhost.

To solve this, I had to redo the installation with a local admin account on the computer and not as an admin user on my enterprise domain.

Found another [post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2141735?start=0&tstart=0) for reference.

I hope this answer will help other guy which encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and painless workaround to get a correct installation is to reinstall by constantly (manually) updating the corrected sqlnet.ora file.

1. Do a first graphic install, oracle will be happy but nothing will work (credentials not resolved on login, fancy "realm does not exist" errors etc).
2. Modify sqlnet.ora as told [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2141735?start=0&tstart=0)
3. Uninstall Ora but keep the modified file in place
4. Open sqlnet.ora with a text editor as admin
5. Reinstall while periodically saving the sqlnet.ora file (once every 2 seconds did it for me)

Comment: However, if there a permissions issue between the installing account and the accounts that will use it (as in the asker's case), this won't actually help.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Windows authentication in
`oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora`

```
# SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

And executing
`oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\CreateDB.bat` after, seems to be enough to repair existing installation.